# How to embed custom media player in Android app?

Tags: javascript, android, html, audio, iframe

I am broadcasting live audio using MIXLR website. The website provides iframe code for embedding it into website. I used the iframe code into html file and integrate it with Android app using WebView method. The application loads html file including the player but it loads the Android video player when I click on play button instead of playing in the player embedded. The iframe code doesn't have any audio file to use it in HTML5 audio tag. Is there anyway to play the audio in same player embedded instead of opening android player?

Comment: maybe you can try this library https://github.com/cprcrack/VideoEnabledWebView

Comment: I tried the above library but same thing happened. This is the url I want to embed (https://mixlr.com/enikaasradio/embed/?autoplay=true) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this code with these setting :

```
WebSettings webViewSettings = webView.getSettings();
webViewSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webViewSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
webViewSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webViewSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(Webview view, String url){
     return false; 
}});

webView.loadData("<iframe src=\"http://mixlr.com/enikaasradio/embed/?autoplay=true\"></iframe>", "text/html", "utf-8");
```

in your manifest add this permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and in your application tag, add this :

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Comment: Thanks. The javascript was disable and caused that issue. It is fixed with above settings now.